# ORDER BY with multiple conditions?

Tags: sql, database, db2

I've got data for products that sort of looks like this:

```
id    order status    discount status    product type
------------------------------------------------------
1     in progress     pending approval   top
2     in progress     approved           top
3     NMI             pending approval   jeans
4     NMI             pending approval   jacket
5     completed       approved           helmet
```

There is a particular order that the products are normally sorted by, which is similar to the following:

```
ORDER BY "order status" DESC, "discount status" ASC, "product type" DESC, "id" DESC
```

Now, this is fine, but I need a particular type of order at the top of the list, which is orders that are both "order status" in progress and "discount status" pending approval.  The rest of the list should follow the order described above.

I know I can use cases to pull that information to the top, but how can I do this without disrupting the rest of the preferred order?  Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using, db2 or mysql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In standard SQL, you can write:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN "order status" = 'in progress' AND "discount status" = 'pending approval'
               THEN 1 ELSE 2
          END),
         "order status" DESC,
         "discount status" ASC,
         "product type" DESC, "id" DESC
```

This should work in both MySQL and DB2.

Comment: I'm using DB2.  I seem to be receiving error code -214: "AN EXPRESSION IN THE FOLLOWING POSITION, OR STARTING WITH position-or-expression-start IN THE clause-type CLAUSE IS NOT VALID. REASON CODE = reason-code"

Comment: @wes . . . That is strange.  DB2 supports the `case` statement and there is nothing strange about this syntax.

Comment: It looks like later down the line this gets preceded with a SELECT DISTINCT which I think is the culprit.  It must have something to do with ambiguity.  Any solution to this?

Comment: "later down the line" and "gets preceded with" is a bit confusing.   Are you building a dynamic statement?  Not that it should matter.  Can you post the complete statement?

Comment: @wes . . . Ask another question and include the entire query, sample data, and desired results.

Comment: I figured this out:  Due to ambiguity this cannot be done in an ORDER BY clause in a SELECT DISTINCT statement.  My solution was to define the CASE outside the ORDER BY clause and then put it in the ORDER BY clause as a new column descending.  Your answer is correct for my original question.